# Why Mininet does not drop any packets?

Tags: delay, packet, mininet, loss

I am trying to collect some network statistics using the Mininet Python API however, I noticed that there are no packet losses even though I have set the link bandwidth and sending more traffic than the configured bandwidth. I thought there possibly could be some error in my code so I went on to use the Mininets built-in topology to see if I still get the same behavior. I started with a linear topology as below:

```
sudo mn --topo linear,3
```

I then ran iperf on h1 and h3 to get the bandwidth and sent more traffic than what the bandwidth was.

```
h1 iperf -s -u -p 2000 -i 1 > server.txt &
h3 iperf -u -c 10.0.0.1 -p 2000 -b 20M -i 1 -t 120 > client.txt &
```

I tired several values of -b however there still was no packet losses.
Then I configured the link bandwidth along with the topology, as below:

```
sudo mn --topo linear,3 --link tc, bw=10
```

Then sent 20M traffic and yet there were no losses again. After some reading and trial and error, I configured the delay as well.

```
sudo mn --topo linear,3 --link tc, bw=10, delay=10ms
```

Then again generated 20M traffic and this time, surprisingly, but as expected, there was ~50% packet loss.

My assumption was that the switches have a sufficiently large buffer which buffers the packets until all are sent and there are no losses. However, when the transmission is constrained by delay, the packets are dropped because they are not able to make it in time.

I have collected the necessary stats for graphing however I want to know why there are no packet losses without the delay parameter?

Comment: (20M - 10m) / 20M ≈ 90% packet loss, isn't it?

Comment: In this case the unit does not really matter. my concern really is why is there no packet loss without the delay parameter

Comment: @ChrisWesseling how did you get ≈ 90%? Sorry if I'm missing something

Comment: 20M = 160 megabit/s while bw=10 = 10 megabit/s, so you drop about 150 thousand of 160 thousand bits sent. (roughly, 1024 vs 1000 and packet sizes make this a rough estimate) But I might have read the docs badly.

Comment: Server and client both use 1000 for conversion by default. Capital and small letters [kmgKMG] are used to signal what value to use for conversion. In our case, 'M' will use 1024 for conversion and 'm' will use 1000 for conversion. By default, they use small letters hence, 1000. So if I write -b 20M on the client then 20*1024*1024bits of data is sent. The server receives 20*1024*1024bits and uses 1000 for conversion i.e (20*1024*1024bits)/1000/1000=20.97≈21Mbits. This is the value that both the client and server report. It took a while to figure out why I'm sending 20M but they report 21Mbps.

Comment: I must have mistaken the convention with the iperf --format flag. :)

Comment: @Deo Do you find the cause?